# Download multiple files, with different final names

Tags: linux, macos, bash, curl, console

OK, what I need is fairly simple.

I want to download LOTS of different files (from a specific server), via cURL and would want to save each one of them as a specific new filename, on disk.

Is there an existing way (parameter, or whatever) to achieve that? How would you go about it?

---

(If there was an option to input all `URL`-`filename` pairs in a text file, one per line, and get cURL to process it, would be ideal)

**E.g.**

```
http://www.somedomain.com/some-image-1.png  --> new-image-1.png
http://www.somedomain.com/another-image.png --> new-image-2.png
...
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, just figured a smart way to do it myself.

1) Create a text file with pairs of `URL` (what to download) and `Filename` (how to save it to disk), separated by comma (`,`), one per line. And save it as `input.txt`.

2) Use the following simple BASH script :

```
while read line; do
    IFS=',' read -ra PART <<< "$line";
    curl $PART[0] -o $PART[1];
done < input.txt
```

---

*Haven't thoroughly tested it yet, but I think it should work.